# JQuery swap IDs and names of html elements

Tags: jquery

I can easily toggle two elements using JQuery's built in function but is there any way to swap the names and IDs of two elements. i.e.

```
<a onclick="jQuery('#MetaKey1, #MetaKey, #enternew, #cancelnew').toggle();return false;" href="#postcustomstuff"><span id="enternew">Enter new</span><span id="cancelnew" style="display:none;">Cancel</span></a>
```

Where MetaKey1 is a text box and MetaKey is a list box. I wan their IDs swapped so that when the form is posted back I can get the MetaKey element value.

Comment: You should really not be mixing your HTML and JS like that.

Comment: Yep, what @JohnP said. JQuery is explicitly designed to allow you to stop using script code inline in your HTML elements. You should use `jQuery().click()` instead of `onclick=''`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't very clear, but if you wish to swap the ids of two elements then you could use something like this :

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var m = $('#MetaKey1');
    var n = $('#MetaKey');
    m.attr('id','MetaKey');
    n.attr('id','MetaKey1');
});
```

Comment: What will happen if the user click on Enter new link and then Cancel more than one time? Will the IDs be swapped again?

Comment: You may have to remove the IDs before adding them as you're not supposed to have multiple IDs with the same name in the document... Someone more up on what the DOM does and is supposed to do in this situation may know better than me, but that's what I'd do.

Comment: Yes indeed they will be swapped again,
This is because each time you click jQuery will call the action defined in our function.
It's best if you give this a try with your application.

Answer (score -1):

//Get the id
var idTextBox = jQuery('#MetaKey1').val("id");

var idListBox = jQuery('#MetaKey').val("id");

//Set the id

jQuery('#MetaKey1').val("id", idListBox);

jQuery('#MetaKey').val("id", idTextBox);

Comment: OK what I have done is copy the value of selected list item into the text box. `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  $('#MetaKey1').change(function () {
   //alert($(this).val());
   $('#MetaKey').val($(this).val());
  });
 });
</script>`